# ASP.NET using AtalaSoft to convert Tiff compression

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, tiff

Using Atalasoft's free SDK, 
http://www.atalasoft.com/free-dotnet-image-sdk

I added reference to the DotImage and DotImage.Lib dlls' to Visual Studio 2010.

My code:-

```
Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage image = new Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage(fileName);
Atalasoft.Imaging.Codec.TiffEncoder encoder = new Atalasoft.Imaging.Codec.TiffEncoder();
encoder.Compression = Atalasoft.Imaging.Codec.TiffCompression.Group4FaxEncoding;
image.Save(fileName, encoder, null); // destroys the original.
```

However when I run the code I get an error on the very first line:-

> Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.

Can anyone help me out with this?

**Update:-**

I added a further line of code:-

```
System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission f2 = new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, fileName);
```

Still the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Philo,

Hi, I'm the support engineer you called in to yesterday. I apologize - after you called in, I received a note from our chief software architect asking us to help you out.

If you are still experiencing your issue, please do call back in and/or create a support case on our portal at https://www.atalasoft.com/support/my-portal/cases

A couple of tings that come to mind from your case: make sure you're targeting either x86 or x64 in your project's platform target (DotImage "has bitness") and make sure you're using the appropriate x86 or x64 Atalasoft references. (I strongly suggest our x86 while getting started as x64 has some additional hoops to jump through to get the licensing working.

Atalasoft does ship some AnyCPU dlls but they're for an extremely limited subset of use cases and if you have referenced those and/or are attempting to target your project to AnyCPU, this will cause all sorts of odd behavior.

Also, if you're targeting our .NET framework 4.0, make sure you're targeting the full framework and not "Client Profile" as DotImage has dependencies on components not present in the Client Profile version.

~DigitalSorceress

Comment: Thanks, The x86 reference worked. I was using my references from AnyCPU dlls. However even though my image goes through the compression mechanism, the final output is still in the original compression (LZW) rather than a group4FaxEncoding.

Comment: It might be because LZW compression is not Bitonal and the above code doesn't handle anything but 1bpp.

Comment: Philo, Indeed - LZW would be the fallback for an image where CITTGroup4 could not be applied... because as you have deduced: CITTGroup4 only works on bitonal images

Comment: No good then, the ability to interchange between compression techniques is paramount. Since the Windows Encoding component only works on the Win 7 OS and fails on both Windows 2003 and 2008 servers. The marriage between GDI and WIC is a failure.

Comment: Philo, For the record, our TiffDecoder does have a SetEncoderCompression event where you could set up a hanlder to provide the best possible compression choice based upon the image pixel format, however, if an image isn't bitonal, then you can't use CITT group 4 because it only works for bitonal images. So if you MUST have group 4 compression, you could convert the image to Pixel1bppIndexed - PhotoFree doesn't include our DynamicThresholdCommand, but you could try one of our other threshold commands to avoid brute force conversion to 1bpp

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the the file with .lic extension in project section on the right side? Make sure about that.

Comment: .lic extension ? could you elaborate a bit more?